# Instruct gradle to use local files

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle

I am trying to build an ionic 4 project for android with this command:

```
ionic cordova build android --verbose
```

The bulid fails with the following error:

> Running command: /path/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /path/build.gradle
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>          - https://dl.google.com/path/gradle-3.3.0.pom
>          - https://dl.google.com/path/gradle-3.3.0.jar
>   ...

When I do `wget https://dl.google.com/path/gradle-3.3.0.pom` I get *404*. 
When I paste the url into the addressbar of my browser however the file does get downloaded. So, I have been able to download the files gradle is having trouble downloading.

Is there a way I instruct gradle to use the local files instead of trying to download them?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is for sanctions and if we can use vpn thats resolved